# Texture Painting: brush wants to be dragged from a site to another

Tags: texture-painting

i was painting in blender using a stencil brush to paint bump information on my model. it worked great until i hit some button i think and now instead of freely drag the brush around i have to drag it from a side to another and it shows a little white line from the point I start to drag it to the point i relase it. i'd like to return to my free drag mode without having to create a new brush. anyone knows how to do it?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you enabled **Smooth Stroke** option:

[image]

The smoothness of the brush is driven instead by its **shape**.

It can be customized by defining points (or choosing one of the six a presets) in the editor of the **Curve** panel:

[image]

On the right, the different result you can get by using each preset.